# Prove that if $A\subseteq B\setminus C$ then A and C are disjoint.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $x\in A\lor x\in C$, then it can be the case that $x\in A\land x\in C$. However, if $x\in A\land x\in C$, this contradicts $A \subseteq B\setminus C$. Therefore $A\subseteq B\setminus C \rightarrow A\cap C= \varnothing$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You wrote “Suppose $x\in A\lor x\in C$”. What if this assumption doesn't hold? You also wrote “if $x\in A\land x\in C$, this contradicts $A \subseteq B\setminus C$”. Why?

Comment: On a technicality, your proof is correct, but all that your proof says is "If A and C are not disjoint, then this contradicts that $A \subseteq B \setminus C$". The first and last sentences just contextualize this middle sentence. This is a correct statement, but it is the statement that you're trying to prove. I'd recommend adding more details as to why this is a contradiction.

Comment: You don't need a contradiction. If $x\in A$ then $x\in B\land x\not\in C\implies x\not\in C$. Since this is true for every $x\in A$, $A\cap C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you suppose that $x \in A \lor x \in C$. If $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, then $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and if an element ever belonged to $A \cap C$ one would have $x \in A \cap C \rightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in C$. Thus, one could write the proof as:

Suppose towards contradiction that there is an element $x$ such that $x \in A \cap C$. Then,
\begin{align*}
x \in A \cap C &\rightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in C\\
&\rightarrow x \in B \backslash C \wedge x \in C\\
&\rightarrow x \in B \wedge x \notin C \wedge x \in C. 
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction derived by the assumption that $A \subseteq B \backslash C$. Thus, there is no element $x \in A \cap C$; i.e., $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: To say that A and C are disjoint is to say that $x\notin A \land x\notin C$ so i just rewrote its form and then considered its negation to try to prove a contradiction, what if x is in A and C?

Comment: So I think that the confusion is here. If $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, then, by definition $A \cap C = \emptyset$. This means that there is no element $x$ such that $x \in A \wedge x \in C$. Negating this fact does not lead to $x \in A \lor x \in C$. Think about this intuitively, saying that $A \cap C$ is not empty, means that there must be an $x$ which is in BOTH $A$ and $C$, and not that there must be an $x$ in one of the two. Does this make sense?

Comment: Right so the correct negation is that $x\in A \land x\in C$ since $\neg(A\cap C=\varnothing)$ is equivalent to $A\cap C \neq \varnothing$. And then we could use that assumption to prove our goal by contradiction?

Comment: The correct negation is the existence of at least one $x$ such that $x \in A \wedge x \in C$ and then one can derive a contradiction through the assumption exacty.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, taking $x\in A\cup C$ is irrelevant and should be omitted, because you take $x\in A\cap C$, which is much stronger a condition.

But the main objection is that you're jumping over the bulk of the proof: you *must* prove that, if $x\in A\cap C$, then this contradicts $A\subseteq B\setminus C$; you can't just state it as a matter of fact.

> Now, where's the contradiction? Since $x\in C$, we know that $x\notin B\setminus C$, by definition of set difference, so a contradiction follows from $x\in A\subseteq B\setminus C$ and $x\in A$.

Comment: To say that A and C are disjoint is to say that $x\notin A \land x\notin C$ so i just rewrote its form and then considered its negation, what if x is in A and C? To my understanding when proving goals of the form $P \land Q$ We prove P and Q separately. So then our goals become $x\notin A$, $x\notin C$. So from here its just using those statements to prove a contradiction. From my understanding my justification is no different from considering $x\in A \lor x\in C$

Comment: @NotFriedrichgauss Sorry, but saying that $A$ and $C$ are disjoint means that no element belongs to both sets. Your goal is *not* to prove that some $x$ belongs to neither $A$ nor $C$.

Comment: To my understanding, we are proving that x cant be in both A and C. When i am told that $A\cap C= \varnothing$ this tells me that it cant be true that x is both in A and C. Is that not correct?

Comment: @NotFriedrichgauss Indeed, you want to prove that no element belongs to both $A$ and $C$. But there's no point in starting from some element in $A\cup C$. You can prove the statement by contradiction, as I did in the spoiler, but that's not the only method. For instance, you can start from $x\in C$ and prove it cannot belong to $A$ (try it).

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from the question that if some element $x$ exists in $A$ it will also exist in $B-C$, because of the definition of the subset, now if an element exists in $B-C$, it will exist in $B$ and not exist in $C$, proving that $A$ and $C$ are disjoint as $x \in A \land x \not \in C$